# Does @@parentid attribute work in Sitecore query?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Sitecore [reference](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/developer/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query001.pdf) talk about some attributes you can use in Query, including @@templatename, @@id and @@parentid etc.

parentid doesn't seem to work - `/sitecore/content//*[@@parentid!='']`  never returns any result.   While `/sitecore/content//*[@@templatename!='']` works fine.    Sitecore version is 6.5 and 6.6.

Has anyone been able to query with @@parentid?  ( Perhaps it uses Ancestor/Descendant table and I'm missing data?? - just a guess )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is attempting to parse the value as a GUID and failing. Instead, try an empty GUID like so:

```
/sitecore/content//*[@@parentid!='{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}']
```

Comment: Cool thank you.  However I'm puzzled by non-empty valid id now. No result with `/sitecore/content//*[@@parentid='{CEA0F336-13DE-45CC-A0A7-5CA9C8961436}']` where the id is my Home node. 

I want to see all attributes value but Sitecore doesn't seem to support xpath `attribute::` or any other way of selecting attribute value.

Comment: By selecting `/sitecore/content//*`, you are essentially searching through every item in your tree. Sitecore query limits the result set to 100 items by default, and it just so happens that Home's children weren't in the first 100 results. By using the `fast:` prefix, your query will be translated into SQL and will therefore increase your precision. That said, neither of these techniques will be as fast as selecting Home's direct descendands directly using `/sitecore/content/Home/*`

Comment: Also, regarding the attributes, Sitecore query is designed to select Items so I'm not sure what attributes you are trying to select. If you are referring to an item's Fields, you can access them like so: `/sitecore/content/Home/*[@MyField='Some Value']`

Answer (score 2):

- `@@parentid` only works in fast query.
- In fast query you can only use ancestor not ancestor-or-self (which doesn't give an error it just does a fallback too ancestor).
- Also you can't use the pipe `|` in fast query to concatenate results of 2 or more queries.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do a "give me the ancestor-or-self of the current node whose parent has id=`{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}`.